# How to search something in chat groups, across SE websites?

Tags: support, chat, search

Is it possible to search something in all the chat groups, across SE websites?

For example, I know how to search on StackOverflow chats (I go to `chat.stackoverflow.com`) and search there, but how to do the same for all the SE websites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such thing is not possible within Stack Exchange itself, so the only workaround I can think of is using Google search and limit it to specific domain.

For example searching for pink unicorn in all [chat.stackexchange.com chat rooms](https://www.google.com/#q=site:chat.stackexchange.com+pink+unicorn):

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking to search chat for other SE sites (not just Stack Overflow), the chat system is available under [chat.stackexchange.com](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) - you can search this just as you would with Stack Overflow chat.

There's also a *third* chat server for this site, Meta Stack Exchange, found at (unsurprisingly) [chat.meta.stackexchange.com](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/). Again, you can search this as you do SO chat.

There is no built-in way to search all three chat networks simultaneously; you need to search each one individually or use an external tool.

Comment: Yes, but it does search in just one site at the time, if I'm not wrong. Right?

Comment: @IonicăBizău Searching on chat.stackexchange.com will let you search across all rooms, on all sites.

Comment: I already tried that, but it doesn't work: compare this [SE chat search](http://i.imgur.com/fT4Ffft.png) with [SO chat search](http://i.imgur.com/wCa6ebu.png). According to you, SE chat search should return more results than SO search, but it doesn't.

Comment: @IonicăBizău I can't actually see those images. Still, just because SE chat has more sites doesn't mean it has more messages or would return more results - SO chat is busier than SE chat.

Comment: No, what I mean is that there are **less** search results in SE than in SO. Assuming that SE includes the SO results, it should return at greater or equal number of results than SO.

Comment: @IonicăBizău It doesn't include the SO results. If you want SO results, you search SO chat; if you want SE results, you search SE chat.

Comment: Wait, isn't StackOverflow part of the SE network? I guess it's special just because it has a custom domain. But that's my original question: how to get results from all the SE sites (obviously, including the ones with custom domains). :D

Comment: @IonicăBizău SO has its own chat network because of its scale: merging SO and SE chat would create a much larger network with more issues to manage. SO is the only site apart from MSE that has its own chat network. To search them all, you just need to, well, search them all. Search each network individually.

Comment: Ah, got it. Thanks, +1